# DOORS DXL: Access attribute value of a specific module baseline via Link Module

Tags: ibm-doors

For a verfikation matrix i am trying to get for a all incoming links the status of an attribute of a specific module baseline.
First I used the DOORS assistent to generate the DXL for all incoming links, the specific module and object attribute I want to analyse. The assisent generated DXL show the attribute state of the current baseline of the module.

I tried to modify the DXL to access a specific baseline without success.

Can anyone support me with this topic ?
Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Remember that links can go to specific baselines. Module "outgoing", baseline 1.0 may have a link to an object of Module "incoming", baseline 2.0. And Module "outgoing", current version may have a link to an object of Module "incoming", current version. In this scenario, if you run the analysis wizard on the current version of "incoming", you should get attributes of the current version of "outgoing". If you start the wizard on version 2.0 of "incoming", you should get the attributes of baseline 1.0 of "outgoing".

As long as your links are correct, the wizard should work for you. The specific line that does this is `load((sourceVersion lr),false)`, as `sourceVersion lr` points to the correct baseline.

By the way, creation of verification matrices should start at the outgoing module, the results that you get are way easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support Mike. Could you explain me how to change "sourceVersion lr" in DXL to a specific baseline ?

Comment: well, I am unsure whether you will get a valid matrix using this approach, but the question how to open / load a specific baseline has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76041356/how-to-load-a-specific-baseline-fron-ibm-doors-using-a-dxl-script