# Open a selected baseline in read only mode

Tags: ibm-doors, readxl

I would like to open a selected baseline of a module.
Here is the code that I use to open any selected DOORS module. Please follow the given steps:

1. Select a DOORS module dynamically in a explorer view.
2. Execute the following simple code `print fullName getSelectedItem` and I can open up the selected module and perform read operations on it. Works!

However when I select the baseline of the same module using the explorer view and run the above code. I get the error message `-R-E- DXL: <Line:1> null Item parameter was passed into argument position 1`

How do I open the baseline from a dynamically selected module using dxl? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite unsure what you are trying to achieve. `print fullName getSelectedItem` will do exactly that: it will print the name of the currently selected item including its project name and path to the DXL console, as you asked some months ago.

"open up the selected module and perform read operations on it" will work independent of whether you printed its name previously.

If you want to open a current version of a module for reading / editing in order to e.g. iterate over each object, you can use the statements `Module m = read (fullName getSelectedItem)` or `Module m = edit (fullName getSelectedItem)`.

To open a specific baseline using DXL, have a look at [How to load a specific Baseline fron IBM Doors using a DXL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76041356/how-to-load-a-specific-baseline-fron-ibm-doors-using-a-dxl-script)

How to open the selected Baseline, I don't know. There is a perm "getSelectedBaseline", but I have not yet found out how to use it, this perm is undocumented.

Hope this helps.